# Two questions about mollifiers

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a smooth function whose laplacian equals 1 everywhere in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$ and $p>1$. Let $B(r)$ be the ball of radius $r>0$ and centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$, and let $ \chi_{r} $ designate the characteristic function of $B(r)$ (it equals 1 on the ball and 0 elsewhere). 
Finally set $g=\chi_{r}f$ and for $n=1,2,...$, let  $\psi_{n}$ be the $ C^{\infty}-$regularization of $ g $, i.e.,
$$ \psi_{n}(\zeta)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{p}}g(y)\phi_{n}(\zeta-y)d\lambda_{p}(y) $$
with $ \phi_{n}(t)=\phi(1-n^{2}\mid x\mid^{2}) $, and 
$\phi(t)$ is equal to $C_{p}e^{-1/t^{}}$ for $|t|>0$ and equals $0$ for $|t|\leq 0$, and $ C_{p} $ is a constant chosen so that 
$$ \sigma_{p}\int_{0}^{1}t^{p-1}\phi(1-t^{2} )dt=1.$$ 
My questions are:

1) If $R>r>0$ and for $n$ big enough, is each $\psi_{n}$  a smooth function with compact support in $B(R)$; i.e., $\psi_{n}\in C_{c}^{\infty}(B(R))$?

2) Is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Delta \psi_{n}=\chi_{r}?$($\Delta$ is the laplacian).

My answers to both questions is yes. I am right?

Comment: You are right and thanks for letting me know. I corrected.

Comment: What is $\lambda_p$ ?

Comment: If you meant $\psi_n = f \chi_r \ast \phi_n$ which is of course $C^\infty_c$ then $\Delta \psi_n = \chi_r\Delta f \ast \phi_n+ f \Delta \chi_r \ast \phi_n + \sum_i (\partial_{x_i} \chi_r)(\partial_{x_i} f) \ast \phi_n$. As $n \to \infty$  the $ \ast \phi_n$ disappear. For $|x| \ne r$ the derivatives of $\chi_r$ are $0$. Whence $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Delta \psi_n = \chi_r\Delta f + T$ where $T = f \Delta \chi_r + \sum_i (\partial_{x_i} \chi_r)(\partial_{x_i} f) $ is a distribution supported on $|x|=r$.

Comment: Sorry I am not following. If $|x|=r$, isn't it that $\chi_{r}(x)=0$?

Comment: $\chi_r$ is constant on $|x|> r$ and $|x| < r$ so its derivatives vanish there. Hence the distributional derivatives of $\chi_r$ are distributions supported on $|x|=r$.

Comment: Sorry, it steel doesn't click: as far as I understand, by definition $\chi_{r}(x)=0$ if $|x|\geq r$. So why $T$ is not zero?

Comment: The distributional derivative of $f(t)=\frac{1+sign(t)}{2}$ is $\delta(t)$. And the value of $f(0)$ doesn't play any role, we only care that $f$ is constant for $t >0$ and $t < 0$.

Comment: Thanks. I think my knowledge of distribution theory lacks something. Do you have a reference for this?